# SQLite error with Laravel migration and storedAs column

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-migrations, laravel-10

I installed a fresh Laravel 10 project. And added a new column to the users migration:

```
$table->integer('test')->nullable()->storedAs('5 * 6');
```

And I get this error when running the migration:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "as": syntax error (Connection: sqlite, SQL: create table "users" ("id" integer primary key autoincrement not null, "name" varchar not null, "email" varchar not null, "email_verified_at" datetime, "password" varchar not null, "remember_token" varchar, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "test" integer as (5 * 6) stored))
```

If I take that exact code and execute it as a query in the sqlite console the statement works:
[image]

My SQLite version is: 3.40.1

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-modifiers) `storedAs()` creates a stored generated column in MySQL/MariaDB and Postgres only.

Comment: I saw that as well, but why would it work executing it directly to sqlite and not through the code? And this worked in Laravel 7, which it what I'm upgrading from.

Comment: Since all SQLSTATE errors come directly from the database driver the Laravel version shouldn't be relevant. Make sure your version of SQLite (that's the version compiled into PHP, not whatever you run from CLI) supports this feature (FWIW the comments in `Illuminate/Database/Schema/ColumnDefinition.php` say it works in SQLite.)

Comment: See also the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html) for generated columns in SQLite. "generated columns are designated using a "GENERATED ALWAYS" column-constraint"

Comment: Your previous comment on cli version being different than what Laravel uses, which is the PDO, is in fact different. PDO is using 3.22, but the cli version is 3.40, I believe this is why it works when I execute and not when the app runs it. My only issue now is that I can't figure out how to upgrade PDO version without upgrading my Ubuntu system. Looks like Ubuntu 18.04 only goes up to SQLite 3.22.

Comment: You must be on an old PHP version if you're coming from Laravel 7, Upgrading that would be a good step, it's likely you'd have problems running Laravel 10 anyway.